# how to use gridSearch CV with scipy?

Tags: pandas, grid-search, sklearn-pandas

i have been trying to tune my SVM using Gridsearchcv but it is throwing errors.

my code is :

```
train = pd.read_csv('train_set.csv')
label = pd.read.csv('lebel.csv')

params = { 'C' : [ 0.01 , 0.1 , 1 , 10]
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC() , params , n_jobs = -1)
clf.fit(train , label)
```

throws the error as : 'too much indices for array'

but when i simply do this :

```
clf = svc()
clf.fit(train.data , label.data)
```

the code works fine

Comment: How is this a Pandas question? Seems more like SciPy to me... Also, consider including a complete verifiable and reproducible example. Which means give a small sample of your data to test answers on...

Comment: @Kartik i have edited it ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem lies with your data structure train.data / label.data. I have tested both versions of your code and they work:

```
import sklearn.svm as sksvm
import sklearn.grid_search as skgs

params = { 'C' : [ 0.01 , 0.1 , 1 , 10]}
X = np.random.rand(1000, 10)  # (1000 x 10) matrix, 1000 points with 10 features
Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000)  # 1000 array, binary labels

mod = sksvm.SVC()
mod.fit(X, Y)
```

Output:

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

and

```
import sklearn.svm as sksvm
import sklearn.grid_search as skgs

params = { 'C' : [ 0.01 , 0.1 , 1 , 10]}
X = np.random.rand(1000, 10)  # (1000 x 10) matrix, 1000 points with 10 features
Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000)  # 1000 array, binary labels

mod = skgs.GridSearchCV(sksvm.SVC(), params, n_jobs=-1)
mod.fit(X, Y)
```

Output:

```
GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score='raise',
       estimator=SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False),
       fit_params={}, iid=True, loss_func=None, n_jobs=-1,
       param_grid={'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]}, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs',
       refit=True, score_func=None, scoring=None, verbose=0)
```

If your data is in dataframe and series the code still works, you can try it by adding:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
Y = pd.Series(Y)
```

after you generate X and Y.

Difficult to say without a reproducible piece of code though. Also you probably should add the label sklearn to the question.

Comment: i think the problem is passing the label as a DataFrame , so what should i do .

Comment: i have used as_type.array()  nothing . @Borja i am losing my sanity over this . please see to it

Comment: You should extract the Series with the labels from the dataframe. Either `label[column_name]` if you know the name of the column, or `label.iloc[:, 0]` if it's the first column or if there's only one column.

Comment: That is: `clf.fit(train , label.iloc[:,0])`

Comment: btw what was i doing wrong here ? ( just a last question )

Comment: DataFrames and Series are different objects which use numpy arrays under the hood. A dataframe is a collection of series and the data is stored as a 2D numpy array, whereas a Series is stored as a 1D numpy array. Normally sklearn expects a 1D array as labels, so I'm guessing when you were feeding it a DataFrame (hence a 2D array) it was somehow getting confused. However I'm not sure why it was working with the SVC() and not the GridSearchCV(), or why with my randomly generated data it was working on both.

Comment: You're welcome :) if this answered your question then please select the answer as accepted answer